# Dota 2 Team Ranked Match Making Ranking (MMR) spread

Tags: dota-2

I know that the highest gap that allows us to play in team in ranked mode is 2000.

I was wondering if it is the solo MMR or the party MMR which counts.

Is it any one of them or just the party MMR?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is likely just the **Party MMR**, since that is the MMR you are playing with.

Single MMR as a statistic is not applied when playing party games.

Comment: I've played with people that were >2k over my solo mmr, but <2k over my party mmr, so I strongly suspect this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually 2k above the AVERAGE party MMR in the team. I often play with my 2K mmr friends, but we need a 3rd person with fairly high MMR to be able to find a ranked game.